# when i rotate bitmap it is scaled automatically in android

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, scale

I am trying to set the minimum and maximum scale factor but when i set it, the rotation on some degree is automatically scaling my bitmap. How can I solve this issue ?

Here is my code that I have done onTouchEvent on bitmap:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    boolean handled = true;

    switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDis = spacing(event);
            if (oldDis > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(event);
                lastRotateDegree = rotation(event);
                isPointerDown = true;
            } else {
                isPointerDown = false;
            }
            isInSide = false;
            isInResize = false;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            isPointerDown = false;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isPointerDown) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);

                //Two-finger rotate
                if(event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    float newRot = rotation(event);
                    float r = newRot - lastRotateDegree;
                    matrix.postRotate(r, mid.x, mid.y);
                }

                //Two-finger scaling
                float scale;
                float disNew = spacing(event);
                if (disNew == 0 || disNew < 10f) {
                    scale = 1;
                } else {
                    scale = disNew / oldDis;
                }
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

                matrix.getValues(arrayOfMatrix);
                float scaleX = arrayOfMatrix[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                float scaleY = arrayOfMatrix[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

                if(scaleX <= 0.7f || scaleY <= 0.7f) {
                    matrix.postScale((0.7f)/scaleX, (0.7f)/scaleY, mid.x, mid.y);
                } else if(scaleX >= 2.5f || scaleY >= 2.5f) {
                    matrix.postScale((2.5f)/scaleX, (2.5f)/scaleY, mid.x, mid.y);
                }

                invalidate();

            }
            break;
    }

public void midPoint(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    mid.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
    double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
    double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no Bitmap instance in your code,

Comment: Bitmap instance is in the onDraw() method and here we don't need bitmap instance. Bitmap is drawn on canvas when invalidate() is called with matrix. This is just onTouchEvent of View.

Comment: Ok, then please help yourself.